# Is it possible to make an angular app as a library?

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-library

I have an angular app generated like this `ng new hello-world` . This hello-world app listens to a file that is present in some directory and compiles it and generates a form in the UI. Now I want to make this app a library such that I can use this library in my node application/backend/just call it in my cli by specifying the args to serve the UI.

I want to use something like this `hello-world --port 4200 --path ./tmpDir/filename.sol`  so the app serves in port 4200.

Comment: You cannot make entire application as library

Comment: can I know how graphql playground and grpc playground are able to generate UI at particular port ?

Comment: Can you elaborate the question? For graphQL you will be running the application in nodeJS / java server.